# Sacar valor de un while en php

Tags: php, bucles

El problema que tengo es el siguiente.

Tengo esta parte de código con la que muestro juegos en la base de datos:

```
$catalogo = mostrarCatalogo();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catalogo)){
      echo'
        <div class="producto">
            <img src="images/'.$row2["idJuegos"].'.jpg" alt="proyecto2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-lotengo">LO TENGO</button>
        </div>
        ';
      }
```

El problema es que no se como sacar el valor de $row2 y pasarlo a otro metodo, sin meterle un return y sacarlo del bucle.

Actualizacion: Quiero que al pulsar sobre el boton lo tengo, me coja el id del juego que en ese momento salga por el while y lo pueda pasar a otra funcion para insertar

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo del método al que quieres pasar la variable?

Comment: Por qué no puedes simplemente llamar a la función desde el bucle?

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia, no tienes un fragmento de cógido representativo, te propongo una cosa: completa el [recorrido](es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y edita la pregunta una vez lo hayas hecho, mejorará la calidad de la pregunta y seguro que la de la respuesta, además esta misma pregunta y su respuesta podrán servirle a otros que también tengan dicha duda. :)

Answer (score 1):

$row2 es un array asociativo, y los valores los tienes con el nombre de la columna o el numero de columna.

dentro del bucle puedes llamar a cualquier funcion que quieras pasando $row2

```
$catalogo = mostrarCatalogo();
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catalogo)){ 
    echo' LO TENGO ';
    echo $row2['nombre_columna'];
    myFunction($row2);
    }
    function myFunction($row){
     // trabajo con row2 (dentro de la función se llamará $row) en una funcion

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente no uses return... no se que queres hacer, pero por ej. en este codigo inserto en un array todos los juegos cuyos ID sean impares...

```
$catalogo = mostrarCatalogo();

$idsImpares = array();
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catalogo)){
      chequearImpar($row2["idJuegos"]);
      echo'
        <div class="producto">
            <img src="images/'.$row2["idJuegos"].'.jpg" alt="proyecto2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-lotengo">LO TENGO</button>
        </div>
        ';
      }

      function chequearImpar($id) {
         if($id%2 !== 0) {
             $idsImpares[] = $id;
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen las demás respuestas, tu pregunta es bastante ambigua, dado que puede tener multiples soluciones dependiendo de lo que desees hacer con el dato del bucle.

Si lo que deseas es utilizar cada dato que encuentras en el bucle para enviarlo a una función para procesarlo puedes utilizar el llamado de una función dentro del bucle.

```
$catalogo = mostrarCatalogo();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catalogo)){

      llamarFuncionQueNecesitas($row2) // Aqui envias en cada iteración del bucle la información

      echo'
        <div class="producto">
            <img src="images/'.$row2["idJuegos"].'.jpg" alt="proyecto2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-lotengo">LO TENGO</button>
        </div>
        ';
      }
```

Otra opción sería agregar todos los datos que estas encontrando en el ciclo para utilizarlos luego. Algo como esto:

```
$catalogo = mostrarCatalogo();
$return_array = array();
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($catalogo)){

      array_push($return_array ,$row2); //guardar cada dato de la iteración para usar en otro momento

      echo'
        <div class="producto">
            <img src="images/'.$row2["idJuegos"].'.jpg" alt="proyecto2">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-lotengo">LO TENGO</button>
        </div>
        ';
      }

llamarFuncionQueNecesitas($return_array) //Enviar el arreglo lleno a donde necesites.
```

Espero te sirva de apoyo para resolver tu problema, cualquier duda avísame.